# Automapper what is the best way to configure mapping profile for a simple child parent structure

Tags: c#, vb.net, mapping, automapper, poco

I have the following POCO

```
Public Class SamplePOCO{
    Public String Id;
    Public String FromSamplePocoId;
    Public String ToSamplePocoId;
}
```

and the following model

```
Public Class SampleObject{
    Public String Id;
    Public SampleObject FromSampleObject;
    Public SampleObject ToSampleObject;
}
```

I want to create a mapping profile on top of something similar to the following with AutoMapper. What is the best way to achieve this?

I would appreciate some help.

**Edit**

Please consider the following. Sorry for not being clear before.

```
Public Class POCOContainerClass{
    SamplePOCO[] SampleList
}

Public Class ObjectContainerClass{
    SampleObject[] SampleList
}

SamplePOCO samplePOCO1 = new()
{
    Id = "100",
    FromSamplePocoId = "200",
    ToSamplePocoId = "300",
};

SamplePOCO samplePOCO2 = new()
{
    Id = "200",
    FromSamplePocoId = "100",
    ToSamplePocoId = "300",
};

SamplePOCO samplePOCO3 = new()
{
    Id = "300",
    FromSamplePocoId = "200",
    ToSamplePocoId = "100",
};

SamplePOCO[] SamplePOCOList = new []{samplePOCO1 ,samplePOCO2 ,samplePOCO3 };

var samplePOCOContainer = new POCOContainerClass{SampleList = SamplePOCOList };

var sampleObjectContainer = _mapper.Map<ObjectContainerClass>(samplePOCOContainer);
```

**Edit 2 (Sorry that it's in VB)**

As you can see here, while mapping a SystemInfo to NetSystem, we first map the zones and save them in a collection, then we can use that collection to relate the nodes with that zone. This is possible because they are two different objects. In my case, I am trying to find a solution for self-referencing types. I hope it's a bit more clear now. I will try to edit for C# and simplify the coede later.

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
        Public Function GetZoneList(ctx As ResolutionContext) As Dictionary(Of String, NetZone)
            Dim zoneList As Dictionary(Of String, NetZone)
            If Not ctx.Options.Items.TryGetValue("zone", zoneList) Then
                zoneList = New Dictionary(Of String, NetZone)
                ctx.Options.Items.Add("zone", zoneList)
            End If
            Return zoneList
        End Function


Public Class CommonNetworkProfiles
    Inherits Profile
    Public Sub New()
CreateMap(Of NodeInfo, NetNode)().ForMember(Function(n) n.Zone, Sub(opt As IMemberConfigurationExpression(Of NodeInfo, NetNode, Object))
                                                                                opt.MapFrom(Of NetZone)(AddressOf MapZoneNamesToNetZoneObjects)
                                                                            End Sub).AfterMap(
            Sub(ni, nn, ctx)
                Dim nodeList = ctx.GetNodeList()
                If Not nodeList.ContainsKey(nn.UID) Then
                    nodeList.Add(nn.UID, nn)
                End If
            End Sub).ReverseMap().ForMember(Function(ni) ni.Name, Sub(opt) opt.MapFrom(Function(nn) nn.Zone.Name))

CreateMap(Of ZoneInfo, NetZone)().AfterMap(
            Sub(zi, nz, ctx)
                Dim zoneList = ctx.GetZoneList()
                If Not zoneList.ContainsKey(nz.Name) Then
                    zoneList.Add(nz.Name, nz)
                End If
            End Sub).ReverseMap()

CreateMap(Of SystemInfo, NetSystem)().ForMember(
        Function(dst) dst.Zones,
        Sub(opt As IMemberConfigurationExpression(Of SystemInfo, NetSystem, NetList(Of NetZone)))
            opt.MapFrom(Function(si, ns, m, ctx)
                            ns.Zones.AddRange(si.Zones.Select(AddressOf ctx.Mapper.Map(Of NetZone)).ToList)
                        End Function)
            opt.SetMappingOrder(2)
        End Sub).
        ReverseMap()


Private Shared Function MapZoneNamesToNetZoneObjects(ni As NodeInfo, nn As NetNode, member As Object, ctx As ResolutionContext) As NetZone
            Dim netZone As NetZone = Nothing
            Return If(ctx.GetZoneList().TryGetValue(ni.Name, netZone), netZone, Nothing)
        End Function
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Why is `C#` tagged?

Comment: Because VB or C# doesn't really matter. I just wanted to get different approaches.

Comment: I don't see any parent-child relationship between your classes.

Comment: Well I don't know how to call that tbh. What I tried to explain with parent-child relation is that the SampleObject is a model and it has FromSampleObject and ToSampleObject with the type of SampleObject. It's basically like a linked list. @DimitrisMaragkos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to first create the `SampleObject` instances based on `SamplePOCO` instances. Then manually iterate over `SampleObject` list and set the `FromSampleObject` and `ToSampleObject` properties based on the `FromSamplePocoId` and `ToSamplePocoId`.

```
public class MyProfile : Profile
{
    public MyProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<POCOContainerClass, ObjectContainerClass>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.SampleList, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => SamplePocoArrayToSampleObjectArray(src.SampleList)));
    }


    private static SampleObject[] SamplePocoArrayToSampleObjectArray(SamplePOCO[] samplePOCOs)
    {
        // create the SampleObject list.
        SampleObject[] sampleObjects = samplePOCOs
            .Select(x => new SampleObject
            {
                Id = x.Id,
            })
            .ToArray();
        
        // link SampleObject references
        foreach (var sampleObject in sampleObjects)
        {
            var samplePOCO = samplePOCOs.First(x => x.Id == sampleObject.Id);
            
            sampleObject.FromSampleObject = sampleObjects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == samplePOCO.FromSamplePocoId);
            sampleObject.ToSampleObject = sampleObjects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == samplePOCO.ToSamplePocoId);
        }

        return sampleObjects;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that it works when mapping from SampleObject to SampleObjectPOCO since I'm mapping from the properties of the source to a string property in the destination. However, this approach wouldn't work for the opposite. When mapping from SampleObjectPOCO to SampleObject, we have only the object Id's and we are trying to assign objects with those Id's to SampleObject.FromSampleObject but the objects with those Id's may have not been created during that. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the update and sorry for not being more clear in the question before. I just updated the question. Can you take a look at it?

Comment: Just add one more mapping from `POCOContainerClass` to `ObjectContainerClass`. Am I missing something?

Comment: That schema exactly proves my point. As you can see, FromSampleObject of [0] is not the same object as [1]. They are just 2 different instances with the same values but they don't reference each other. I will add an example with another type that is not self referencing and you will understand my point.

Comment: Hey Dimitris, were you able to understand what I shared in the latest edit? @DimitrisMaragkos

Comment: In the end, I did something very similar to the example you shared. Thank you for your answer.